# How to buy sandbox for Salesforce commerce sandbox

Tags: sandbox, licenses, commerce-cloud

I want to buy sandbox for my developer. We are going to have training on salesforce commerce cloud developing. Could you please help to show me how to contact and where to buy these sandboxes.
Thanks and look forward to hearing from you soon. 
Yours sincerely, 
Tuyet Tran

Comment: by contacting your salesforcec rep/ regional rep or contacting salesforce themseleves? salesforce's contact info can be founf on their website, this is nto the best place for this...

Comment: thanks. i have tried to contact but no replies yet. Seems that the information is not public

Answer (score 2):

I assume you already have a production org and one or more sandboxes that have been allocated for other purposes.

Contact your [Account Executive](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/133392/102) to add an additional Sandbox license. As per [How is a Salesforce Sandbox licensed?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/82484/102) there isn't a public pricing structure that applies to everyone. It will depend on your production org edition and additional features, such as Commerce Cloud.

See also:

- [Sandbox Types and Templates](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=create_test_instance.htm&type=5)

Comment: There's actually a Commerce Cloud Support request type for this so you don't need to go through A Customer Success Manager (CSM) or Account Executive.